# Convert input file or stream to UTF8 and detect if it's UTF8 or not (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8

what would be the best way in C#/asp.net to do the following:
- detect if file is reliably UTF8 or not;
- convert input stream or just file on disk to UTF8 programmatically.

Cheers Askar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For checking if stream is UTF8 see: http://utf8checker.codeplex.com/

For converting it you can use StreamReader:

```
new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
```

In fact, using this contructor prevents you the previous check, you can just use it.

MSDN:

> The character encoding is set by the encoding parameter, and the
>   buffer size is set to 1024 bytes. The StreamReader object attempts to
>   detect the encoding by looking at the first three bytes of the stream.
>   It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and
>   big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the appropriate byte
>   order marks. Otherwise, the user-provided encoding is used. See the
>   Encoding.GetPreamble method for more information.

If you wish it not to detect little-endian Unicode and big-endian Unicode call the following contructor:

```
new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, false))
```

The `false` will turn off the Encoding detection, and thus this call will allways encode the file using UTF 8.